# Is there an overview page in Azure, listing all kinds of currently used resources?

Tags: azure

I'd like to see what resources I'm currently using on Microsoft Azure, without being required to wade through each kind of service type.

Is there an overview page, listing all resources currently in use by my account, probably listing each entry with a checkbox, so I can easily delete/release unused resources from that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Portal, Click on Subscriptions then select your subscription and then click on `Resources` from the left hand side menu. That should show all the resources in that subscription.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As shown in below screenshot, you can type 'Recent' in search box and then click on it to find the list of all kinds of currently / recently used Azure resources and then clear them as a whole or remove any specific resource.

Also, few of those recent resources are by default shown in your home page of the portal.

[image]

[image]

[image]